# How to use Spring boot, JOOQ and Flyway together?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jooq, flyway

So, let's consider a general `Spring boot` application, which uses `JOOQ` for database database access, and `Flyway` for database migration. The project uses `gradle` for dependency management.

I want the following things:

1. Run my application in docker. So, I want to use only in environment variables (https://12factor.net/config). Hence, I don't know, how to configure **both** spring boot application properties (database login and password) and gradle JOOQ plugin database login and password.
2. Automatic generation JOOQ classes. Flyway migration runs, when an application has started. But JOOQ generates code in `gradle build` task. So, we see wrong order of tasks execution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a very similar setup, but resorted to manual action to generate Jooq classes.
I need them for development, so it makes no sense for me to delay the generation till target environment.

I decided to run a local dB for development purposes.
I run it in docker, but this is a detail in the entire setup.

When I have a new migration, I run it with flyway grade plugin against the local dB. Then I regenerate Jooq classes with grade Jooq plugin.

When the app is deployed in the target environment, I rely on flyway to run migration on startup. I have matching Jooq classes packaged, so everything works smoothly.

Comment: hello, am I right, that you commit JOOQ classes to git?

Comment: Yes, I commit them after adding every migration file (and frankly speaking, I don't find it disturbing). Additional dB on the local PC is a bit of a pain, but I learned to live with it.

Comment: thank you. Soo, I did almost like you. I thouth, that there is some more cool way.

Comment: I'd be happy to find a better one as well, so please share in this thread if you happen to find one.

Comment: I'm following this   https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6551#issuecomment-481305842

Comment: if you are using gradle, you can also use: https://github.com/ayedo/jooq-modelator

Answer (score 1):

The jOOQ GitHub project has an [example project](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/master/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-spring-boot-example) that uses jOOQ with Spring Boot and the `sql-maven-plugin`.

You can easily replace the `sql-maven-plugin` by the Flyway plugin as demonstrated in the [jOOQ/Flyway example project](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/master/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-flyway-example) or [this blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/2014/06/25/flyway-and-jooq-for-unbeatable-sql-development-productivity/).

On a related note, in case you're using one of the commercial distributions of jOOQ with Spring Boot, this is documented [in this blog post here](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/06/26/how-to-use-jooqs-commercial-distributions-with-spring-boot/).

Answer (score 0):

There is the following gradle task, which requires flyway, otj-pg-embedded, jooq and postgresql driver:

```
import com.opentable.db.postgres.embedded.*
import org.flywaydb.core.*
import org.jooq.codegen.*

tasks.named("compileKotlin") {
    doFirst {
        //create embedded postgresql
        EmbeddedPostgres.builder().setPort(5400).start().use {
            //migrate embedded posrtgresql
            Flyway.configure()
                .locations("filesystem:$projectDir/migrations/")
                .schemas("public")
                .dataSource(it.postgresDatabase)
                .load()
                .migrate()

            //generate jooq classes
            GenerationTool.generate("some xml for jooq")
        }
    }
}
```

The source is https://gist.github.com/whyoleg/63195b60eb85e8fe2114b30f28b892ef